# Ubuntu 16.04 Clipboard - Highlight issue

Tags: 16.04, clipboard

I've got a new installed Ubuntu 16.04 working fine. However in a previous version 14.04 (same machine) we can send **text-item1** to Clipboard and simultaneously highlight **text-item2** using mouse. We were able to keep these two items available for Copy/Paste one using the ctrl-v and the other by using the mouse two-buttons.

However in 16.04 this is not possible now. If you select text-item1 and send it to Clipboard (Ctrl-C) and then you highlight only text-item2 it will overwrite the content of Clipboard with text-item2.

This result in an impossibility on the following case:

1. Create a new folder "**Untitled Folder**"
2. Select and send to Clipboard a "**new-folder-name**" text to be used to rename "**Untitled Folder**",
3. However, once you press F2 on "Untitled Folder" to apply the new name, the text **Untitled Folder** goes immediately to Clipboard (as it is highlighted) overwriting "new-folder-name".

Does anybody know how to correct this issue?  If so what are the steps.

Thanks